# Is it correct Event+DependencyProperty?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, wpf-controls

```
    // Property
    IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl),new UIPropertyMetadata(false, 
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsSelectedChanged)));

    // Event
    public event RoutedEventHandler SelectedChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(SelectedChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SelectedChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    // How Do I Raise the Event ???
    static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = (MyControl)source;

        // ???? 
        s.OnSelectedChanged(source, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to raise a `RoutedEvent`, just call `this.Raise(...);`

if you are calling in a static method, call it like so:

```
((MyControl)s).Raise( new RoutedEventArg( MyControl.MyEvent ) );
```

Comment: @serhio: You can use your `s`.

Comment: @serhio: `s.RaiseEvent(EventArgs.Empty)` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx)

Comment: @serhio: ... or whatever are the correct args for your event (should be seen at `SelectedChangedEvent` declaration)

Comment: found `s.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SelectedChangedEvent, s));`

Comment: Also, in general, I doubt about the necessity of declaring such a event for a dependency property... but have no choice, apparently.